# CSS not loading in webhosting provider

Tags: css, web-hosting

I have developed a HTML5 website and was working perfectly fine in my localhost. But when i try to host the same pages in **000webhost.com** all the CSS , Images , JS files are not loading, which are working good in my xampp localhost.

Folder Structure from hosting provider 
[image]

```
//index.php code - this is by default available in the .htaccess folder, do i need to modify something here?

<?php
// Powered by Zyro
include dirname(__FILE__).'/vXXXXX,com/index.html';
?>
```

Error Logs from Console when loading the index.html page fro hosted server.
[image]

This is the first time i am hosting with this hosting provider, and facing the same issue of not loading the CSS with other projects also.

Did i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

In the folder structure , there is an index.php given by the hosting provider by default. Deleting the index.php file and moving my html files out of the folder and placing along with htaccess files has worked.